# How to translate a custom permalink for a CPT custom taxonomy?

Tags: url, advanced-custom-fields, slug, wpml

I am trying to translate custom slugs for CPTs and taxonomies but I get a 400 error

Wordpress, WPML, ACF, ACFML All latest updates used in a development site with primary language English and secondary language Greek.

I have created a CPT through ACF called "traditions"(Tradition / Δρώμενο) and custom taxonomy for it called "seasons" (Season (ENG) / Εποχή (Greek)).

ACF->Post Types->Traditions->Advanced settings->URLs->Permalink Rewrite=Custom Permalink + URL slug=thrace/traditions/%season%

ACF->Taxonomies->Seasons->Advanced settings->URLs->Permalink Rewrite=Custom Permalink + URL slug=thrace/traditions/

This allows to have the following structure:

/thrace = page

/thrace/traditions = subpage

/thrace/traditions/autumn = custom taxonomy "season"

/thrace/traditions/autumn/lorem-ipsum = custom post type "tradition"

I have tried to translate the url - slug through:WPML->settings-> slug translations (check)WPML->settings->Post Types Translation->Traditions (traditions)->Set different slugs in different languages for Traditions->thrace/traditions/%season% (english original) -> thraki/dromena/%season% (greek translation)

Parents work properly: /thrace/traditions/translates to /el/thraki/dromena/

Taxonomy archive page also translates properly /thrace/traditions/autumn/https://wp.emthrace.org/el/thraki/dromena/fthinoporo/

However when clicking on the custom post type itself I get an error as the /%season%/ part of the custom url defined in the acf advanced tab for the CPT does not translate correctly. /thrace/traditions/autumn/lorem-ipsum/and the error /el/thraki/dromena/%season%/dromeno01/

instead of

/el/thraki/dromena/fthinoporo/dromeno01/

I suspect the % in thw wpml slug translations messes things but I don't know if there is another way to call and inject that taxonomy between the subpage and the cpt within the url.